# How to convert time of day into radians with 0/2Pi = sunrise and Pi=sunset?

Tags: r, datetime, data-conversion, radians

I have a big dataset (continuous across months), and I need to perform circular statistics  to assess a potential effect of diel cycles.

For this, I converted all cyclic data into radians. I need now to do the same with the time of the day. The problem that I am facing is the following:
I do not want 0/2Pi to correspond to 0h/24h and Pi to noon. I need my data to be standardised, considering that sunrise/sunset time varies through the year.

Instead, I would need to set 0/2Pi to be sunrise and Pi to be sunset times. I've been looking everywhere and couldn't find any solution. A scientific paper uses this method, I contacted one of the authors but no answer so far. Here is a sentence from the paper:

*"To standardise daylight, radian values were calculated. The values 0 and 2Pi represent dawn, while Pi represents dusk."* Zein *et al*., 2019

I should mentioned that I am a marine biologist, working on cetaceans. I do not have any mathematical background. And I code in R. I accessed sunset/sunrise times for everyday of my dataset using sunriset() from the Maptools package.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getSunlightTimes` in `suncalc` package. Here is an attempt to compute the time, setting 0 for sunrise and π for sunset.

```
library(suncalc)
library(hms)

#  tm = a time variable
tm <- as.hms(
  c(
    as.POSIXlt("2019-04-18 10:02:29"),
    as.POSIXlt("2019-04-18 15:10:00"),
    as.POSIXlt("2019-04-18 18:54:12")
  )
)

sun_t <- getSunlightTimes(as.Date("2019-04-18"), lat= 59.33, lon= 18.07, tz= "CET")

sunrise <- as.hms(sun_t$sunrise)
sunset <- as.hms(sun_t$sunset)

tm_pi <- as.numeric(tm - sunrise) * pi / as.numeric(sunset - sunrise)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I got my sunrise/sunset from another package but anyway that's fine :)
Your way makes sense, definitely, but the problem is that the time from sunrise to sunset isn't the same than the time from sunset to next sunrise! In your calculation there, does it account for that then? 

I don't think so because taking arbitrary values, it doesn't work.

Comment: `as.numeric(sunset - sunrise)` is the time from sunrise to sunset on the date, here 2019-04-18, in Stockholm (given as 59.33º N 18.07º E).